# Error instance PhantomJS in Async Jersey

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, jersey-2.0

I have made a simple Async Web Services with Jersey. In one API I want to use PhantomJs, so I try this code:

First in my dao file:

```
Book getBook() {
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability("takesScreenshot", false);
    caps.setCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.loadImages", false);
    caps.setCapability(
            PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY,
            "/home/carl/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs");

    driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
    // ....selenium code...
}

ListenableFuture<Book> getBookAsync(){
    ListenableFuture<Book> future = 
        service.submit(new Callable<Book>() {
            public Book call() throws Exception{
                return getBook();
            }
        });
    return(future);
}
```

and in my Resource I have:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ManagedAsync
public void getBook(@Suspended final AsyncResponse response){
    ListenableFuture<Book> bookFuture = dao.getBookAsync();
    Futures.addCallback(bookFuture, new FutureCallback<Book>() {
        public void onSuccess(Book book){
            response.resume(book);
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable thrown){
            response.resume(thrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Error:

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class org.json.JSONObject, genericType=class org.json.JSONObject.
```

Comment: i try and post the error

Comment: i try with Tomcat, and i have: Asynchronous processing not supported on Servlet 2.x container

Comment: i set this in my web.xml: <async-supported>true</async-supported> and now i have this error: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=text/html, type=class org.json.JSONObject, genericType=class org.json.JSONObject.